# How do I smooth/fix my glock model?

Tags: modeling

I am pretty new to Blender.

I have tried smoothing vertex and beveling but it does not look good. Is there any way I can possibly fix this?

[image: 1]

Comment: Have you tried smooth shading? Select your model > right click > shade smooth. Then go to Properties > Object Data Properties > Normals and check Auto Smooth.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you @Geri that seems to have done the trick. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try shading it smooth by right clicking your object and selecting "shade smooth". Or, if you don't want it all to be shaded smooth, you can go into Edit mode, selecting the vertices of the part you want to shade smooth, hitting "p", and select "separate selection", and then going into object mode and shading that smooth.

Comment: Thank you too @Bently Carpenter . :)

Comment: @Tomi If you like this answer, could you please accept it, so that it won't be on the unanswered list (and so I can get some reputation?) ;)